# JavaScript Code for image rotation on a web page

Tags: javascript

How does this look for basic image rotation?  What is there to be improved here?

```
<p>    
  <img src='images/rotation/dsc_0052.jpg' id='rotateImg0' alt='image rotation' />
  <img src='images/rotation/bilde1.jpg' id='rotateImg1' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation'  />
  <img src='images/rotation/bilde2.jpg' id='rotateImg2' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation' />
  <img src='images/rotation/bilde3.jpg' id='rotateImg3' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation' />
  <img src='images/rotation/bilde4.jpg' id='rotateImg4' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation' />
  <img src='images/rotation/dsc_0043.jpg' id='rotateImg5' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation' />  
</p>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
      var rotation = function () {
          var currentImage;
          var count = function () {              
              // Figure out how many images we have on the rotation          
              var x = 0;
              while (document.getElementById('rotateImg' + (x + 1).toString()))
                  x++;
              return x;
          } ();

          var hideImages = function () {
              // Hide all the images              
              for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                  document.getElementById('rotateImg' + i.toString()).style.display = 'none';
              }
          };

          var showImage = function (number) {
              document.getElementById('rotateImg' + number.toString()).style.display = 'block';
          };

          var fn = {};
          fn.setupRotation = function () {
              // Show the first image
              currentImage = 0;
              showImage(currentImage);

              // Start the rotation
              var interval = setInterval("rotation.advanceRotation()", 4000);
          };

          fn.advanceRotation = function () {
              if (currentImage + 1 == count)
                  currentImage = 0;
              else
                  currentImage++;
              hideImages();
              showImage(currentImage);
          }

          return fn;
      } ();

      rotation.setupRotation();      
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things I noticed:

**1. Looking through the document with DOM methods is a slow process.** There's often no way around it, and it won't crash anything here, but try to minimize it when you can. From page 183 of Stoyan Stefanov's *JavaScript Patterns*:

> DOM access is expensive; it's the most common bottleneck when it comes
>   to JavaScript performance. This is because the DOM is usually
>   implemented separately from the JavaScript engine...
>
> The bottom line is that DOM access should be reduced to a minimum.
>   This means:
>
> - Avoiding DOM access in loops
> - Assigning DOM references to local variables and working with the locals
> - Using selectors API where available
> - Caching the length when iterating over HTML collections

I've done that here. I created one extra variable named `images` and assigned it an empty array. Then, using your counting function, I store the image references in it.

```
var currentImage,
    images = [],

      ...

    count = (function () {              
      // Figure out how many images we have on the rotation          
      var x = 0;
      while (document.getElementById('rotateImg' + (x + 1).toString())) {
        images[x] = document.getElementById('rotateImg' + x.toString());
        x++;
      }
      return images.length;
    }()),
```

(If you're able to change the HTML, you can avoid the loop altogether and collect these images in one line. Just add an `id` to the element that contains them...

```
<p id="container">
  <img src='images/rotation/dsc_0052.jpg' id='rotateImg0' alt='image rotation' />
  ...
</p>
```

...and collect them with...

```
var images = document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("img");
```

But this doesn't help you if you can't change the markup.)

Now you can run `hideImage` and `showImages` on the array instead of having to walk the DOM every time.

**2. When the first argument to `setInterval` is a string, the browser runs `eval()` -- an implementation of the JavaScript compiler -- on it before firing.** That's also expensive and unnecessary here. From page 111 of Douglas Crockford's *JavaScript: The Good Parts*:

> The browser provides `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions that can
>   take string arguments or function arguments. When given string
>   arguments, `setTimeout` and `setInterval` act as `eval`. The string
>   argument form also should be avoided.

Getting rid of the quotes and the closing parentheses makes it a plain old function reference, which works fine.

So I changed this:

```
var interval = setInterval("rotation.advanceRotation()", 4000);
```

To this:

```
var interval = setInterval(rotation.advanceRotation, 4000);
```

**3. Not crucial here. You can do all your variable declaration with one `var` statement per function.** This reduces the chances of your variables being overwritten or unavailable due to hoisting. From *JavaScript Patterns* again:

> JavaScript enables you to have multiple var statements anywhere in a
>   function, and they all act as if the variables were declared at the
>   top of the function... This can lead to logical errors when you use a
>   variable and then declare it further in the function.

So I took out the multiple `var` statements and declared them all at the top of the outer function.

The final code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title>Rice Flour Cookies' image rotation test</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <p>    
      <img src='images/rotation/dsc_0052.jpg' id='rotateImg0' alt='image rotation' />
      <img src='images/rotation/bilde1.jpg' id='rotateImg1' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation'  />
      <img src='images/rotation/bilde2.jpg' id='rotateImg2' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation' />
      <img src='images/rotation/bilde3.jpg' id='rotateImg3' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation' />
      <img src='images/rotation/bilde4.jpg' id='rotateImg4' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation' />
      <img src='images/rotation/dsc_0043.jpg' id='rotateImg5' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation' />  
    </p>
  </body>
</html>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var rotation = function () {
    var currentImage,
        images = [],
        count,
        hideImages,
        showImage,
        fn;

        count = (function () {              
          // Figure out how many images we have on the rotation          
          var x = 0;
          while (document.getElementById('rotateImg' + (x + 1).toString())) {
            images[x] = document.getElementById('rotateImg' + x.toString());
            x++;
          }
          return images.length;
        })();

        hideImages = function () {
          // Hide all the images              
          for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            images[i].style.display = 'none';
          }
        };

        showImage = function (number) {
          images[number].style.display = 'block';
        };

        fn = {};
        fn.setupRotation = function () {
          // Show the first image
          currentImage = 0;
          showImage(currentImage);

          // Start the rotation
          var interval = setInterval(rotation.advanceRotation, 4000);
        };

        fn.advanceRotation = function () {
          if (currentImage + 1 == count)
            currentImage = 0;
          else
            currentImage++;
            hideImages();
            showImage(currentImage);
        };

        return fn;
    } ();

  rotation.setupRotation();      
</script>
```

And you can see it at work here:
http://james.da.ydrea.ms/riceflourcookies/rotate.html

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented most of what you suggest on my (private) site.  It works very well.